# How do I get these random bonuses and what are they

Tags: heroville

Sometimes an icon pops up in the game and starts moving around.  You can click it for a temporary bonus, but how are these initiated (is it just random?) and what are they.

[image: Image of wealth bonus with freehand circle for clarification]

So far I've found a wealth bonus (doubles gold from sales) and a speed bonus (makes each tick take half a second).

Comment: There is also a [Power Bonus](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uHMmM.png) that doubles hero damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrades are random events that occur during gameplay, they are not triggered, rather they spawn every 10-20 minutes.

The three available are as stated

- Wealth (Double gold)
- Speed (Half tick time)
- Power (Double Damage)